# Javascript paste event iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, paste, jquery-events

I wan't to capture a  paste event on iPhone. Using Javascript jQuery. I'we tried jQuery `keyup` and `paste` without luck. Any suggestions?

This is what I've got:

```
 $("#MyInputFields input").eq(0).bind("keyup paste", function () {
    //do something
});
```

Everything works fine if the user types the value in the input field, but if the user pastes the text it does not fire.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html and http://quirksmode.org/dom/events/cutcopypaste.html might help you out.

Answer (score 1):

**If** your selector is correct, I think the only option is that you are missing the DOM ready, because everything else in that code looks o.k.

```
 $(function (){ $("#MyInputFields input").eq(0).bind("keyup paste", function () {
        //do something
    });
});
```

Unless those inputs aren't present in the page when this line executed, then you need to use delegate event like `on`\ `delegate` \ `live` :

```
$('body').on("keyup paste", "#MyInputFields input", function () {
        //do something
    });
```

chose the function base on your jquery version:

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

Comment: The paste event does not trigger on iphone. The keyup does the trick on every other browser/platform i'we tested. And the element is there at load, so no need for live etc.